# Get results from Ajax call

Tags: r, ajax, rstudio

Maybe this is a really stupid question but I want to use an ajax call and work with the result in R. Here is the call from www.randomuser.me:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?format=csv?results=5000',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

So what is the easiest way for me to save the csv so I can then work with it in R? Is that possible directly in R? I would really appreciate a low level answer (I have no idea what jQuery etc. is)

Comment: Look into use `httr` to make a simple `GET` request to that endpoint. you can leave javascript/ajax out of it.

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON("https://randomuser.me/api/?format=csv?results=5000")` works just fine to get the data but, as @MrFlick noted, `httr:::GET` will be more flexible in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `httr` package and make it a proper API function vs concatenate query params (which is super error prone):

```
library(httr)

random_user <- function(user_count=1, 
                        gender=NULL, # NULL params don't end up passing values for those fields
                        password = NULL,
                        nationality = NULL, 
                        include_fields = NULL,
                        exclude_fields = NULL, 
                        seed = NULL) {

  httr::GET(
    url = "https://randomuser.me/api/",
    query = list(
      results = user_count,
      gender = gender,
      password = password,
      seed = seed,
      nat = nationality,
      inc = include_fields,
      exc = exclude_fields,
      format = "csv"
    )
  ) -> res

  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  res <- suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(httr::content(res, as="parsed")))

  res

}
```

In use:

```
x <- random_user(100)
glimpse(x)
## Observations: 100
## Variables: 25
## $ gender            <chr> "female", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "m...
## $ name.title        <chr> "ms", "mr", "mr", "ms", "mrs", "ms", "mr", "mr", "mr", "ms", "mr",...
## $ name.first        <chr> "josefa", "xenócrates", "nero", "elen", "yasemin", "ella", "robert...
## $ name.last         <chr> "calvo", "da conceição", "barros", "teixeira", "erçetin", "thomsen...
## $ location.street   <chr> "7854 calle mota", "9652 rua são jorge", "7557 rua quatro", "9576 ...
## $ location.city     <chr> "parla", "francisco morato", "itabira", "petrópolis", "artvin", "a...
## $ location.state    <chr> "andalucía", "bahia", "rondônia", "são paulo", "amasya", "syddanma...
## $ location.postcode <chr> "89193", "60020", "12989", "10994", "16543", "41488", "68794", "78...
## $ email             <chr> "josefa.calvo@example.com", "xenócrates.daconceição@example.com", ...
## $ login.username    <chr> "blueswan335", "whitemeercat215", "organicladybug700", "yellowduck...
## $ login.password    <chr> "interacial", "siemens", "theater", "cupcake", "enrique", "caberne...
## $ login.salt        <chr> "yMTLU5A4", "QWIGWlHA", "k7FifdOw", "kdTfS4wQ", "xQn4xxXJ", "saGW2...
## $ login.md5         <chr> "cd72739b62cf65bf98e9c100007cb15b", "cbec674fc38c97fc101b86a1d3a71...
## $ login.sha1        <chr> "5e039ceb350c4cdd3ebd46689b09d4619e286396", "8eeb0afb6f56a47f9de15...
## $ login.sha256      <chr> "81e0dc00e947a5909d80eefee32107300e2b9721160e3e2b84781392434d6234"...
## $ dob               <dttm> 1961-03-22 03:03:07, 1975-04-17 11:04:20, 1974-09-27 01:32:22, 19...
## $ registered        <dttm> 2013-05-07 12:16:02, 2002-11-29 18:23:46, 2011-01-12 03:11:21, 20...
## $ phone             <chr> "970-460-274", "(40) 5146-2153", "(37) 0732-7652", "(93) 1003-7035...
## $ cell              <chr> "674-010-743", "(36) 0114-6484", "(75) 8899-4318", "(04) 0678-4231...
## $ id.name           <chr> "DNI", NA, NA, NA, NA, "CPR", "DNI", "DNI", "CPR", "NINO", "SSN", ...
## $ id.value          <chr> "18765757-R", NA, NA, NA, NA, "388682-5305", "94865867-K", "517030...
## $ picture.large     <chr> "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/32.jpg", "https://rando...
## $ picture.medium    <chr> "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/32.jpg", "https://r...
## $ picture.thumbnail <chr> "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/32.jpg", "https:/...
## $ nat               <chr> "ES", "BR", "BR", "BR", "TR", "DK", "ES", "ES", "DK", "GB", "US", ...

x
## # A tibble: 100 x 25
##    gender name.title name.first    name.last            location.street
##     <chr>      <chr>      <chr>        <chr>                      <chr>
##  1 female         ms     josefa        calvo            7854 calle mota
##  2   male         mr xenócrates da conceição         9652 rua são jorge
##  3   male         mr       nero       barros            7557 rua quatro
##  4 female         ms       elen     teixeira       9576 rua santa luzia
##  5 female        mrs    yasemin      erçetin          9542 kushimoto sk
##  6 female         ms       ella      thomsen           1099 nøddelunden
##  7   male         mr    roberto       campos 1046 calle de ángel garcía
##  8   male         mr     hector    hernandez     5523 paseo de zorrilla
##  9   male         mr     sander     andersen             1625 sneppevej
## 10 female         ms    susanna     anderson            8476 the avenue
## # ... with 90 more rows, and 20 more variables: location.city <chr>, location.state <chr>,
## #   location.postcode <chr>, email <chr>, login.username <chr>, login.password <chr>,
## #   login.salt <chr>, login.md5 <chr>, login.sha1 <chr>, login.sha256 <chr>, dob <dttm>,
## #   registered <dttm>, phone <chr>, cell <chr>, id.name <chr>, id.value <chr>,
## #   picture.large <chr>, picture.medium <chr>, picture.thumbnail <chr>, nat <chr>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. I'm at my dayjob now so I can't really get into it. But I will in the evening / on the weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rjson` package to query that URL and parse the returned JSON data into an R list:

```
> library(rjson)
> url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?format=csv?results=5000"
> data = rjson::fromJSON(file=url)
> str(data)
List of 2
 $ results:List of 1
  ..$ :List of 12
  .. ..$ gender    : chr "female"
  .. ..$ name      :List of 3
```

Note the format and results parameters are ignored here, because your URL query string is `format=csv?results=5000`, and you should separate parameters with `&`, not `?`.

If you want to read from a CSV source, **fix the URL** and then read from the URL:

```
> url2 = "https://randomuser.me/api/?format=csv&results=5"
> d = read.csv(url2)

> dim(d)
[1]  5 25
> names(d)
 [1] "gender"            "name.title"        "name.first"       
 [4] "name.last"         "location.street"   "location.city"    
 [7] "location.state"    "location.postcode" "email"            
[10] "login.username"    "login.password"    "login.salt"       
[13] "login.md5"         "login.sha1"        "login.sha256"     
[16] "dob"               "registered"        "phone"            
[19] "cell"              "id.name"           "id.value"         
[22] "picture.large"     "picture.medium"    "picture.thumbnail"
[25] "nat"              
>
```